# Does Amazon S3 browser based upload support input "multiple option?

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3

Does [Amazon S3 browser based upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?HTTPPOSTExamples.html) support input "multiple" option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each form can only 'submit' a single file to S3. To upload multiple files you would need multiple forms.

From the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectPOST.html): Forms Fields - File

> You cannot upload more than one file at a time

Answer (score 1):

To upload multiple files use http://flajaxian.com/

Answer (score 0):

In this Tutorial Jeffrey Way from NetTuts Create a form that allows for uploading multiple files at once with S3 Amazon an Uploadify Plugin, this is a Premium Tutorial but if you are interested check the link.

[S3 Uploader](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-custom-s3-uploader-new-premium-tutorial/)

Comment: Im asking about non-flash direct upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload multiple files by adding the `multiple` attribute to your file input tag as follows:

`<input type="file" name="file" multiple />`

Before the form is submitted, you would need to set the 'key' input field for each file.  This works well with the [jQuery File Upload widget](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

In the following examples, just add `multiple` to the file input field and it should work.

[Rails example](http://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/)

[PHP example](https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/direct-upload-to-s3-using-aws-signature-v4-php/)

Comment: But then wouldn't the value of the `input[name=key]` need to be an array? Otherwise, all the files would upload to the same location on s3, right?